# Generate Graphql Type from mongoose schema with subfields

Tags: mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

I'm starting to build a Graphql service to go alongside with a REST api already in production, using NodeJS and Mongoose, but I'm having some trouble in finding a way to translate my mongoose schema to a GraphQL type.

I have the following schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String},
    imageURL: {type: String, default:null},
    providerId: {type: String, required: true},
    token: {type: String, required: true},
    history: [{
        orders:[{type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Order'}],
        restaurant: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Restaurant'}
    }]
}, { timestamps: true});
```

So, basically, the trouble is the `history` field. This field is a list an object with 2 subfields: orders (list of Objects that reference another mongoose schema) and restaurant (that reference the mongoose schema for restaurant).

My main question is: when writing the corresponding GraphQL type for "User", is there a way to create subfields, as I did with mongoose on the `history` field, or I have to create a second Type and then reference this type (knowing that there's no need for the application to create another schema in mongoose, whould only create in GraphQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, when you write your GraphQL schema, history will need to be a separate type, as will probably Order and Restaurant. Using Apollo, the schema type definitions would look something like:

```
type User {
  # additional fields
  history: [Record!]!
}

type Record {
  orders: [Order!]!
  restaurant: Restaurant
}
```

In addition to the type definitions above, you would also provide a resolver for User. In this case, the resolver would simply return `User.findOne()` (or however you normally get the User object from your database).

Here's the neat part: you may not even need resolvers for Order, Restaurant or even History. When you don't specify a resolver, GraphQL will use a default resolver that happily uses the object it's passed (whatever chunk of the User object you would pass in your resolver for the User type). If it finds keys in that object that match the fields in you specified in your GraphQL schema's 
type definition, it will populate those fields and ignore everything else.

Of course, if you need additional control (maybe your object keys and field names don't match), you can always still write the resolver yourself.

Comment: My doubt was really if I needed to create a separate type for history, since I hadn't in Mongoose. So I'll do that. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @ThiagoNascimento You could get away with using a [JSON custom scalar](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json) instead but then you're severely limiting what can be requested (i.e. anyone requesting the field will not be able to narrow it down further to just restaurants, or just a few fields from each order). You also lose the ability to easily stub out or mock individual fields within history.

Comment: Didn't know that,but I'm probably going for separate types so I can have more flexibility in the requests

Comment: One more question: when referencing an mongoose object using mongoose ObjectID, do I have to populate the field in the graphql resolver? So it would be something like:  User.find().populate(fields)

Comment: Yes, presumably, you'll need to call populate for any fields that reference other documents in MongoDB. Assuming you're letting the default resolvers do most of the heavy lifting, you'll want the resolver for your query to return an object that matches the structure you've outlined in your schema.